# How can I increase the process limit (ulimit -u) for X users on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, ulimit

Between having, ahem, "a few" tabs open in Firefox and occasionally having to use Chromium, which is a crazy process hog (something like 12 processes *per tab*), I often find myself hitting the process limit (`ulimit -u`), even though I have enough memory and the system isn't really under load.

I'd like to increase the limit, but I can't figure out how. Docs say to edit something in `/etc/security/limits.d`, and this seems to work... *for root*. But it doesn't work for my normal user. (Maybe the X session is resetting it lower?)

How do I increase the limit for my normal user?

Note:

```
# grep -vE '^#' /etc/security/limits.conf

# ls /etc/security/limits.d
95-jack.conf  99-increase-process-limit.conf
# cat /etc/security/limits.d/99-increase-process-limit.conf 
* hard nproc 4096
* soft nproc 4096
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weeeeell... no one else was going to be able to answer this, because PEBKAC. Sort of.

Turns out, it works a lot better when `.bashrc` *doesn't* look like:

```bsh
# ...do stuff...

ulimit -u 2048

# ...do other stuff...
```

...derp!

(I'd totally forgotten about this, and suspect this was left over from a previous attempt to raise the limit from 1024. Once that was gone, changes via `limits.d` worked.)